# Disappearing rows after using pivot_wider() & unnest() in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| case_id | contact_id | reviewer_id | submitted | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_1 | no |
| 123 | 11 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_1 | yes |
| 456 | 12 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_1 | no |
| 456 | 13 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_1 | yes |
| 789 | 14 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_1 | no |
| 789 | 15 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_1 | no |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_a |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_b |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_c |
| 123 | 11 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_a |
| 456 | 12 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_a |
| 456 | 13 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_a |
| 789 | 14 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_a |
| 789 | 15 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_2 | response_a |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_3 | yes |
| 123 | 11 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_3 | yes |
| 456 | 12 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_3 | no |
| 456 | 13 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_3 | no |
| 789 | 14 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_3 | no |
| 789 | 15 | reviewer_1 | yes | question_3 | yes |

I needed to restructure this data frame so that each question is its own column. To do this, I did following:

```
df_new <- pivot_wider(df_old,
                  names_from = question,
                  values_from = answer) %>% clean_names()
```

The above code produced the following data frame with nested lists at different points in every column. (Here, I only show a nested list for question_2, contact 10, but in the actual data frame every column has nested lists periodically.)

| case_id | contact_id | reviewer_id | submitted | question_1 | question_2 | question_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | c("response_a", "response_b", "response_c" | yes |
| 123 | 11 | reviewer_1 | yes | yes | no | yes |
| 456 | 12 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | no | no |
| 456 | 13 | reviewer_1 | yes | yes | no | no |
| 789 | 14 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | no | no |
| 789 | 15 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | yes | yes |

To unnest the data frame, I did the following:

```
  df_new <- df_new %>% unnest(c(question_1)) %>% unnest(c(question_2) %>% unnest(c(question_3)
```

This unnested the rows for cases 123 and 456, but not 789. Instead, 789 just disappeared from the data altogether. Here's what it looked like:

| case_id | contact_id | reviewer_id | submitted | question_1 | question_2 | question_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | response_a | yes |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | response_b | yes |
| 123 | 10 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | response_c | yes |
| 123 | 11 | reviewer_1 | yes | yes | no | yes |
| 456 | 12 | reviewer_1 | yes | no | no | no |
| 456 | 13 | reviewer_1 | yes | yes | no | no |

To figure out the cause, I tried to isolate 789 into it's own data frame by using filter(str_detect(case_id, "789") == TRUE). But to my surprise, this caused 789 to disappear once again, leaving me with an empty data frame.

Interestingly, I don't have this problem when I just select rows instead of filtering, such as using df_new[5:6,].

At this point, I'm completely stuck. I checked the data types, and each variable is listed as character, so I don't think it has to do with that, but I could be missing something. I'm also not returning any errors. I'd appreciate any help or ideas to resolve this.

**EDIT:**

Below is the result of running dput(df_old). I replaced my real variables with filler responses and significantly truncated the output, but otherwise the result is the same.

```
structure(list(encounter_id = c("123", "123", 
"123", "123", "123", "123", "123"), coder = c("10", "10", 
"10", "10", 
"10", "10", 
"10"), submitted = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), question = c("question_1", "question_2", 
"question_3", "question_4", "question_5", "question_6", "question_7"), response = c("response_a", "response_b", 
"response_c", response_d", 
"response_e", "response_f")), row.names = c(NA, -206L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is dput also run on df_new.

```
structure(list(case_id = c("123", "123", 
"456", "456", "789, "789", 
"789"), reviewer_id = c("10", "10", 
"10", "10", 
"10", "10", 
"10"), submitted = c("1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), question_1 = list(
    "Yes", 
    "No", 
    "No", 
    "No"), question_2 = list(
    c("response_a", 
    "response_b", "response_c", 
    "response_d"
    ), c("response_e", 
    "response_f"
    ), c("response_g", 
    "response_h", 
    "response_i", "response_j"
    ), "response_a", "response_a", "response_a", 
    "response_a"), question_3 = list(
    "response_k", 
    "response_k", "response_k", 
    "response_k", "response_k", 
    "response_k"), question_4 = list(
    c("response_l", "response_m", 
    "response_n"), "response_1", 
    c("response_m", "response_o", 
    "response_p"), "response_l", 
    "response_l", "response_l", 
    "response_l"), question_5 = list(
    "response_p", "response_q", NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? Do you expect the same number of values for each question for a given record? If you have a different number (ie question 2 has 3 values, question 3 has 4 values), how do you want to reconcile that difference in the output? Are you assuming that missing values will be inserted?

Comment: please share the result of `dput(df_old)` in your question

Comment: Sure. I just added this to the end of the original post above.

Comment: @MrFlick - the desired output is to rearrange df_old so that df_new has individual columns for each question with the responses beneath. I'd like the output to just show NULL or NA where a case does not have as many values as another. I'm rearranging to this new structure just fine. The problem is when I try to unnest.